# Is there a standard for specifying message/stream datatype of unix pipes?

Tags: unix, types, stream, pipeline, messaging

[Wiki article about unix pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) says that "output text of each process (stdout) is passed directly as input (stdin) to the next one", but obviously it's not just about text, but it can be any byte stream chunked into pieces that piped processes produce/consume. Is there a standard that regulates streamed data over such pipeline, or nix designers/ideologists were just hoping that user is 'smart enough' to combine producers and consumers in compatible manner?

Comment: no, there is no and cannot be such standard

Comment: @IłyaBursov would you mind to elaborate on 'cannot be' part?

Comment: mostly because it will break backward compatibility, even if we imagine such standard - consumers still support only some data format to work with it, so user will still have to be smart enough to use appropriate consumers, so such indication will be moslty useless (pretty much like it is now with content-type http field)

Comment: so you think someone can't design backward-compatible standard? Let's say, if stream starts with some magic sequence of bytes, it may mean that stream conforms to certain standard and 'smarter' cli tools can assume certain structure of streamed data, but if not - its business as usual and smart cli tools will issue a warning or just barf. It may resemble a type system in modern programming languages to a degree.

Comment: Let me challenge your claim that metainformation about data stream is useless ... its like saying that type system in programming language is useless because the whole thing still relies on developer to write code that passes compiler type-checks.

Comment: my point was that users will still have to know that util is smart or not and combine them in appropriate manner, so there will be no gain for users, just additional workload for developers to support and mess because of mixing of new/old tools, btw - many standard files have standard headers and some mime tools can detect them by reading first bytes. so there is no obvious benefit in such standard, but obvious downsides, this is why it is useless

Comment: as for downsides you mentioned: end users won't have to know if it is smart or not, they'll just use tools available to them, because such standard could be backward-compatible. But I agree that using first bytes of a stream for data type detection will be a much simpler approach in many scenarios.